# How to request for multiple ads in a single DFP request

Tags: android, admob

I am requesting ads from dfp using the below code but I want to request multiple ads in a single request and store them in an arraylist (or similar data structure) and use them at multiple places as and when required.

I tried to put the request inside a for loop but it is not seem to be working.

Here is the code I am using to fetch ads from dfp

```
private void refreshAd() {

        templateAdLoadedListener = new NativeCustomTemplateAd.OnCustomTemplateAdLoadedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomTemplateAdLoaded(NativeCustomTemplateAd nativeCustomTemplateAd) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onCustomTemplateAdLoaded: ad fetched");
                customTemplateAds.add(nativeCustomTemplateAd);
            }
        };


        templateAdClickListener = new NativeCustomTemplateAd.OnCustomClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCustomClick(NativeCustomTemplateAd nativeCustomTemplateAd, String s) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AboutWebActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("TYPE", "AD");
                intent.putExtra("TITLE", "AD TITLE");
                Log.d(TAG, "onCustomClick: url = " + String.valueOf(nativeCustomTemplateAd.getText("Click-through URL")));
                intent.putExtra("URL", String.valueOf(nativeCustomTemplateAd.getText("Thirdpartyclicktracker")));
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        };


        adLoader = new AdLoader.Builder(MainActivity.this,"ad_unit_id")
                .forCustomTemplateAd("ad_template_id", templateAdLoadedListener, templateAdClickListener)
                .withAdListener(new AdListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAdFailedToLoad(int errorCode) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onCustomTemplateAdFailedToLoad: error code = " + errorCode);
                    }
                }).build();


        adLoader.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());

}
```

I tried to put **refreshAd()** function inside a for loop but it is not working. What is the best way to fetch multiple ads in a ad single request?